# How do I make Portal be a single page all on it own

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Sorry, extreme React newbie. I have a simple react function component:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Portal() {
    return (
        <h2>Portal</h2>
    );
}
```

In my App.js I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Portal from "./components/Portal/portal";
import LogoHeader from './components/LogoHeader';
import NewFooter from "./components/NewFooter";

function App() {    
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/portal">
                        <Portal />
                    </Route>                    
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
            ...
            <LogoHeader />
            ...
            <NewFooter/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

In LogoHeader I have a link:

```
<a href='/Portal'>Portal</a>
```

When I click the "Portal" link it refreshes the page, but it now displays the "Portal" header at the top and then the rest of the App.js page. How do I make Portal be a single page all on it own?

**UPDATE**

Based on an Answer given by @DrewReese I have changed App.js Render to:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
            <p className="greeting">Hello, {token.firstName}</p>
            <LogoHeader />
            <GetCategories />
            <Navbar id="customNav" navItems={navItems} shopCategories={shopCategories} />
            <Switch>                    
                <Route path="/home">
                    <Slideshow id="slideshow" />
                    <div id="productContainer">
                        <br />
                        <h3>Featured Products</h3>
                        <br />
                        <FeaturedCards />
                        <br />
                        <h3>Most Popular</h3>
                        <br />
                        <ProdCard />
                        <br />
                        <h3>New Products</h3>
                        <br />
                        <ProdCard />
                    </div>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/portal">
                    <Portal />
                </Route>                    
            </Switch>
            <NewFooter />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an anchor tag (`<a href="...." />`) it will trigger a page reload, which reloads your React app. You should use the `Link` component to link to pages within your app.

LogoHeader

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Link to='/portal'>Portal</Link>
```

If you want the header to display rendered pages then move it up in the JSX. Remember, any links you render need to be rendered within a routing context, so the header should be rendered within the `BrowserRouter` component.

App

```
function App() {    
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <LogoHeader />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/portal">
            <Portal />
          </Route>                    
        </Switch>
        <NewFooter/>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want the `Portal` page to be rendered and the header ***not*** to be rendered, then you can render a custom header and conditionally render `LogoHeader` based on route matching.

[useRouteMatch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch)
[matchPath props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/matchPath/props)

> It returns null when provided pathname does not match path prop.

```
const Header = () => {
  const match = useRouteMatch("/portal");
  return !match ? <LogoHeader /> : null;
}

function App() {    
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/portal">
            <Portal />
          </Route>                    
        </Switch>
        <NewFooter/>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Update

Within the `Switch` component, path order and specificity matter. Order ***more*** specific paths before ***less*** specific paths. "/portal" is more specific than "/" so it should be rendered earlier. This is because the `Switch` component *exclusively* matches and renders routes (*i.e. only the first match found*), as opposed to the `Router` that *inclusively* renders them (*i.e. all matches*).

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <BrowserRouter>
      <p className="greeting">Hello, {token.firstName}</p>
      <LogoHeader />
      <GetCategories />
      <Navbar id="customNav" navItems={navItems} shopCategories={shopCategories} />
      <Switch>                    
        <Route path="/portal">
          <Portal />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
          <Slideshow id="slideshow" />
          <div id="productContainer">
            <br />
            <h3>Featured Products</h3>
            <br />
            <FeaturedCards />
            <br />
            <h3>Most Popular</h3>
            <br />
            <ProdCard />
            <br />
            <h3>New Products</h3>
            <br />
            <ProdCard />
          </div>
         </Route>          
      </Switch>
      <NewFooter />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: For my home page route I have `<Route path="/home">`. But now my home page only shows the Header and Footer. The `Portal` is working however. If I use `<Route path="/">` for my home page route, everything shows no matter what.

Comment: @Randy Where & how are you rendering other routes?

Comment: I have put an update in my original question with routes shown.

Comment: @Randy Are you saying that on the `path="/home"` that neither the slideshow component nor the div are rendering?

Comment: @Randy The updated code you shared looks good to me. How and where are you linking to the "/home" route, and are you rendering more than one router in your app?

Comment: No that's everything. But it should be `path="/"` not `path="/home"`. But when I do that it shows both when I choose `Portal`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you just need to use `<Link to="/portal">` from react-router here.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom' (v4 of react-router)
import { Link } from 'react-router' (v3 of react-router)
```

There are 2 issues with using a tag:

1. it does contains relative urls (for this particular case it won't be a problem, but it confuse you on some pages).
2. it triggers page refresh

More info about using Link
https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: I am sorry, I tried your suggestion. I still had the same effect but without a page refresh. Perhaps I am missing something...